# Is it possible to create a SAS token for a directory in DataLake Gen2 storage?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-lake-gen2, sas-token, azure-sas

I have an Azure Function that triggers from a directory (namespace) nested within an [ADLS Gen 2 storage container](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2387#issuecomment-634429802).

**Example:**
`ADLS_AccountName/topLevelContainer/Directory1/Directory2/{name}`

Unfortunately, the Function requires the `Connection string` of the entire DataLake as an input binding (stored as an app setting in `local.settings.json`).

This is far too much permission for a Function to have.

**How do I generate a SAS token for a given nested namespace and use that as the app setting for the Function?**

Comment: Please see my comment below your proposed answer. Unfortunately, there is no way an ACL setting can be used as an Azure Function input binding. Also, granting ACL perms on a *nested* directory grants permissions on all *parent* directories of the nest. This doesn't work for my use case. I imagine there are a lot of people who need this functionality (they just don't know it yet). Could be very powerful if implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer marked as correct is no longer accurate. Please look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.datalakesasbuilder?view=azure-dotnet
Starting service version 2020-02-10 it is possible to generate SAS token for a directory in an ADLS Gen2 account.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the Python SDK equivalent?

Comment: @ericOnline, please check [generate_directory_sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake?view=azure-python#azure-storage-filedatalake-generate-directory-sas).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **it is not possible to create SAS token for a specific folder in ADLS Gen2 storage account**. But you can leverage [`Access Control List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#access-control-lists-on-files-and-directories) to grant permission to a specific file or directory.

You can associate a security principal with an access level to your directories and files from your application. (Note: ACLs apply only to security principals in the same tenant)

If you are granting permissions by using only ACLs (no RBAC), then to grant a security principal read or write access to a folder, you'll need to give the security principal Execute permissions to the container, and to each folder in the hierarchy of folders that lead to the desired folder/file.

Here is an example gets and sets the ACL of a directory named `my-directory`. The string `user::rwx,group::r-x,other::rw-` gives the owning user read, write, and execute permissions, gives the owning group only read and execute permissions, and gives all others read and write permission.

```
public async Task ManageDirectoryACLs(DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient)
{
    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =
        fileSystemClient.GetDirectoryClient("my-directory");

    PathAccessControl directoryAccessControl =
        await directoryClient.GetAccessControlAsync();

    foreach (var item in directoryAccessControl.AccessControlList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }


    IList<PathAccessControlItem> accessControlList
        = PathAccessControlExtensions.ParseAccessControlList
        ("user::rwx,group::r-x,other::rw-");

    directoryClient.SetAccessControlList(accessControlList);

}
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control).

Comment: There are many moving parts! RBAC on the DataLake, ConnectionString/AccountKeys for the DataLake, ACL's for the directories, SAS tokens for top-level directory of the DataLake ("Container") and individual blobs. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to dial these in so that 1.) the Function is ONLY *monitoring* a single directory within the DataLake ("trigger binding") AND 2.) only has access to this single directory. The ACL's you mention *almost* solve #2, but because RWX on a parent directory gives access to ALL child directories, this doesn't work in my use case. Need a single directory scope.

Comment: Ended up using a separate, dedicated ADLS Gen2 Storage Account and keeping SAS tokens scoped to the Container level.

Answer (score 0):

Directory scoped SAS tokens are supported since authentication version `2020-02-10`, see [Directory scoped shared access signatures (SAS) generally available](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/directory-scoped-shared-access-signatures-sas-generally-available/).

The **Python** package `azure-storage-file-datalake` provides the function [`generate_directory_sas`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake?view=azure-python#azure-storage-filedatalake-generate-directory-sas).

For **TypeScript/JavaScript** check the package `@azure/storage-file-datalake` and its function [`generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-datalake/?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-storage-file-datalake-generatedatalakesasqueryparameters) with setting `{ isDirectory: true }` of [`DataLakeSASSignatureValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-file-datalake/datalakesassignaturevalues?view=azure-node-latest).

```
generateDataLakeSASQueryParameters(
  {
    pathName: 'my/folder',
    permissions: DirectorySASPermissions.parse('r'),
    isDirectory: true,
    ...,
    version: '2020-02-10'
  }, ...);
```